# Deja dup backup to external drive - metadata file not found in backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

This has happened a few times but I've left it and just manually backed up data files. This is a basic backup to an external hard drive. When Deja dup does the final step of validating the backup, it has returned this error several times in a row:

> Could not restore ‘/home/briligg/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not
>   found in backup

What do I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure that the user the backup service runs as has read permission to the file or read and execute permission to the directory where the file is located.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) -

1) I deleted the folder ~/.cache/deja-dup

2) I made a new, empty folder named deja-dup

The next two backup runs did not generate an error message.

```
       Don
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `.deja-dup-ignore` file in `~/.cache/`

```
rm ~/.cache/.deja-dup-ignore
```

resolved the problem.